# DocuSign : Modifying the content of an attachment before sending

Tags: c#, pdf, docusignapi

I have requirement to use docusign to send document to sign.
I tried this and its working but it is only for pre-defined template.

Can anyone please suggest how to change the content of an attached pdf, before sending it to recipient.

I will be sending PDF to many person to sign and each person may have different data in that PDF.

So is it possible to change content of the template of Docusign before sending it for sign?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DocuSign NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.Integration.Client.dll/) to integrate a C# application and through that you can easily request a signature on a document if you don't want to use a server-template, though it has support for templates as well.

It also has support for tabs so you can add editable data fields for your recipients if you want to get data from them and let them edit some fields.  You can NOT, however, edit the actual PDF as you suggest, you can only overlay DocuSign tabs on top of it or replace or add new documents to the envelope.

The client is also open-sourced on GitHub so you can modify the source if needed and contribute updates to the library through pull requests.

https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-.NET-Client